# Style ExoPlayer subtitles view from xml

Tags: android, exoplayer

I declare SubtitleView in my fragment like this:

```
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SubtitleView
    android:id="@+id/exo_subtitles"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/red500"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

But I can't see any changes with subs while I change xml file.